# M. Viana, K. Oliveira. Foundations of Ergodic Theory. Chapter $5$, Ergodic Decomposition. Page $143$

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, convex-analysis, ergodic-theory

M. Viana, K. Oliveira. Foundations of Ergodic Theory. Chapter $5$, Ergodic Decomposition. Page $143$.

In this case, is not every subset measurable ?

I mean $\hat B$ consists of all subsets ?

[image]

Comment: I don't see why all subsets should be measurable... Is your reasoning that each $P \in \mathcal{P}$ is measurable and $\pi^{-1}(\mathcal{Q})$ is a union of such $P$'s? If so, that reasoning is not valid, since we only know in general that *countable* unions of measurable sets are measurable (any non-measurable set is a union of singletons).

Comment: @mathworker21 yes this is my reasoning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Consider $M=\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathcal{P}\cong [0,1)$ where I've declared $x\sim y$ if $x-y\in \mathbb{Z}$. Then, you can check that $\hat{\mathcal{B}}$ is simply the ordinary Borel algebra on $[0,1)$ (it stems from the fact that the quotient map is a quotient map in the topological sense, when $\mathcal{P}$ is identified with the circle).

Comment: Like, take $B$, a non-Borel subset of $[0,1)$ and note that $[0,1)\cap \pi^{-1}(B)=B,$ so $B$ cannot be an element of $\hat{\mathcal{B}}$.